# Three.js "camera.setLens(data.focalLength)", disables rotating model/geometry interactively

Tags: javascript, three.js, perspectivecamera

Three.js newby here looking for advice please

My Project loads a 3D obj model, which can be interactively rotated using slider built into the user interface; which works fine. However I need to set the three js camera's field of view according to the focal length of a photo, hence - "data.focalLength". As soon as I include the line in the code: `camera.setLens(data.focalLength);`
 all rotational functionality gets disabled. The console returns the line `TypeError: model.userData.tweakRot is undefined glMain.js:271:4` as soon as you attempt to rotate the model.

My [Git Gist](https://gist.github.com/3skimo/96e6356a30fbb9406487#file-glmain-js) lines 212 - 332 contain the code relating to the above( *I would of JSfiddled it, but unfortunately it doesn't really provide any extra insight* ).

Perhaps you could please tell me which lines to log in the console so we can diagnose the issue?

[three.js perspective camera library](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js) (2nd function)

Comment: The three.js code you are linking to is many years old. Update to the current version, where the function has been changed. Then re-post, preferably with a simple, live example.

Comment: I've updated the link to the latest version and can confirm the library i'm using is the latest minified version. It is difficult to upload a simple live version as it loads external 3d models, which i can't work out how to configure with js fiddle. If theres any other particular detail you'd like please let me know

Comment: [Here is a fiddle you can edit.](http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/.) Do not reproduce your entire project. Reproduce the issue only.

Comment: Thanks for that. For it to emulate my project in a minimal fashion it would at least have to have separate functions for loading , rotating, moving a mesh/model. Camera.lookat is also an integral feature which I've tried to include to "lookAt" the "mesh" but it doesn't work